# what is best way to set state in react on component update? My Render method gets the updated data but component does not updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have three tabs on top of my orders screen. Its data is like this:

```
state = {
  ordersTabItems: [
    { id: 2, name: 'Incoming', isSelected: false, itemsCount: null },
    { id: 3, name: 'Processing', isSelected: false, itemsCount: null },
    { id: 4, name: 'Completed', isSelected: false, itemsCount: null },
  ],
  activeTab: 'incomming',
  inc: '',
};
```

I am rendering it using a **flatlist** in my render method. In the render method I also get variables from store like incommingCount, processing Count and CompletedCount. So once the data updates in Tabs, Count values of each tab changes. Which can be seen updated by putting a debugger on render.

I want to update my ordersTabItems on based upon props received from **redux store**. I don't have any idea which **life cycle** method should I choose here.

Comment: Two answers are stating that you should use `componentWillReceiveProps`, but this API will soon be removed from React https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops. I'd highly recommend that you at least take a look at the official docs before writing your code.

Comment: In fact, you do not need to use componentWillReceiveProps. When your component received updated props it will update automatically. If you are using a listener for the store, once the store is updated your props will also be updated

Comment: @gianni yes, components updates that's why I am getting the data in render methods. but notifications on my tab are showing outside the render methods. using the itemsCount  property of ordersTabData. which is rendered through flat list

Comment: I used componentWillReceiveProps, and it works fine. But I guess it'snot best way of doing it. Because React doc doesn't recommend to use it.

Comment: I would create a function and call it inside the render method, I write it in a separate answer so you can check it

Answer (score 0):

You should use `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle to track changes of props from redux store by comparing `this.props` and `nextProps`.

Once you find changes, update state properly which will lead to re-rendering of component. If you put more detailed code and descriptions, I can help you asap.

Comment: let me try doing this first. one issue though. why React doc says this " Note:

These methods are considered legacy and you should avoid them in new code:

UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate()
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()"

Comment: If you're not using the latest react(16) it's fine. However, if you're on latest react, it is higly recommended to use `getDerivedStateFromProps`

`static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
}`
Inside this function, logic is same.

Answer (score 0):

Once you update the store. You can get updated global state within connected component in componentWillReceiveProps like this :

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  //invoke function with updated store
  //this.foo(nextProps) any method you would like to invoke and setState there

  console.log(this.props); // prevProps
  console.log(nextProps); // currentProps after updating the store
  }
```

And you can also use getDerivedStateFromProps

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
   }
```

Comment: Note: `componentWillReceiveProps()` is [being **deprecated**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops), `getDerivedStateFromProps()` is the preferred method for the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like this:

```
const updateActiveTab = (tabId) => {
  this.setState(...this.state, activeTab: tabId)
```

}

Then  you can call the function in the render() method:

```
this.updateActiveTab(this.props.activeTabId)
```